# Torrent tracker reply with same peer id for every request?

Tags: java, tracker

I'm writing a Java app to look at the trackers listed in a torrent file.

I send the following:

```
http://pow7.com/announce?info_hash=%3f%99%79%31%73%27%9e%be%1d%d2%cd%5f%af%98%7c%17%5f%43%89%f3&peer_id=-jT1000-122843C6A4B0&port=6881&downloaded=0&left=0
```

But it doesn't matter what info_hash I send I either get the same peers ip address back (74.253.253.31:6757) or an error.

Any ideas why this happens?

Best regards,
TX

Comment: In the spec it says: info_hash 
    The 20 byte sha1 hash of the bencoded form of the info value from the metainfo file. Note that this is a substring of the metainfo file. Don't forget to URL-encode this. Is this one of the "info/pieces" in the torrent file? or how do I geneerate this hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer to my question:
One needs to generate a SHA1 hash from the value of the info key.  I take all the bytes from **d** (included, next byte after the word "info") to the last **e** of the info map (included).

Thus is will be SHA1 of the bold part of the snippet below:

...:info **d5:filesld6:...[many bytes]...e** 9:...
(With out the spaces in front of d and after e)

Then I simple convert the byte array returned by MessageDigest and insert % for every hex 2 digit pair. E.g.:

%70%47%8F...[snip]...%13%6F%6C

Comment: You should click the tick next to your own answer to show thats right rather than annotating the question with [SOLVED]